# Does P(E|H) > P(E) => P(H | E) > P(H) explain correlation between bayesian and frequentialist results?

Tags: bayesian, frequentist

I have just noted in the Ross book that given `P(E|H) > P(E)`

> If the occurrence of B makes A more likely, does the occurrence of A make B more likely?

we can conclude that `P(E|H) / P(E) > 1` and, because `P(H | E) P(E) = P(E|H)P(H)` it follows that `P(H | E) /P(H) = P(E|H)/P(E) > 1`, which says that `P(H | E) /P(H) > 1` or `P(H | E) > P(H)`. That is, if evidence has higher chances in the [column that used by frequentist then hypothesis will also enjoy the higher probability in the bayesian table](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/242801/128373). It seems that there is a correlation between two types of inferences. Why is correlation not absolute, why are the differences, can you say that in the broad lines?