# Wald test for Poisson distributions

Tags: statistical-significance, poisson-distribution, count-data, wald-test

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155392/likelihood-based-hypothesis-testing/155420#155420) asks:

> $N_A$ and $N_B$ are variables of the counts of the number of events
>   'A' and events 'B' respectively. Those variables follow Poisson
>   distributions with parameters $\lambda_A$ and $\lambda_B$.
>
> In nature I made one observation of each variable; I observed $n_A$
>   events 'A' and $n_B$ events 'B'. From those, I am asking: Are
>   $\lambda_A$ and $\lambda_B$ equal or different?
>
> **How can I make a hypothesis testing on the null that the rates $\lambda_A$ and $\lambda_B$ are the same?**

The answer suggest to use a Wald test with this formula:

$$Z=\frac{\widehat{\lambda}_1-\widehat{\lambda}_2}{\sqrt{\frac{{\widehat{\lambda}_1}}{n_1}+\frac{{\widehat{\lambda}_2}}{n_2}}}$$

Based on the comments here, I suppose $n_1, n_2$ are what the questioner calls $n_A, n_B$. But I'm not sure about $\widehat{\lambda}_1$ – I would assume that it is the estimate for $\lambda_1$, but isn't that just $n_1$ (as the highest probability that one sees $n$ occurrences is when $\lambda = n$)?

Comment: Your post is highly confusing. You start by defining the $\lambda_i$ as random variables, but then you talk about the $\hat{\lambda}_i$ (i.e. as if the $\lambda$s were parameters -- which is consistent with the conventional usage). You then talk about the $n_i$ (which is defined in the question at the link you gave as observed values -- realizations of $N_1$ and $N_2$) as if they were random variables, which they aren't. Please  distinguish your random variables from your parameters & your observations, and check the question at the page you link to for a definition of the notation it uses.

Comment: I agree with @Glen_b that your question is confusing. Maybe a look at [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9561/checking-if-two-poisson-samples-have-the-same-mean) (or its links) will help you get oriented, and maybe provide a useful test. If you get oriented without finding a solution, perhaps edit your question so someone can help.

Comment: Thanks Glenn and Bruce – I have tried to update my question, does this help? Basically: it seems like this equation requires four variables but I only know two.

Comment: To apply the answer you referenced, you need to take $n_1=n_2=1$ because you have exactly one observation from each distribution.