# Should I report credible intervals based on HDI or QI?

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, bayesian-network, credible-interval

I have highly positively skewed outcome variable. I need to publish my results in an academic journal.

[tidybayes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidybayes/vignettes/tidy-brms.html) allows calculating credible intervals (CI) using **median** or **mean** with high density intervals (**HDI**) or quantile intervals (**QI**).

**Should I report mean and HDI or median and QI?** Probably reporting mean and QI is not a good practice?

Comment: Do you have to choose either or? Are the two very different (probably since it is very skewed)? What do you want to communicate? Perhaps you could show the distribution itself in a figure?

Comment: Considering that most of the research bases on frequentist statistics, which of them is more close to confidence intervals. HDI?

Comment: In frequency arguments as in Bayesian ones there are many many ways of defining an interval that captures, say, 79% of the distribution. Many of them make sense. It is really your choice based on what makes sense for the application. This question is similar to yours and might help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24588/quantile-intervals-vs-highest-posterior-density-intervals